# Is Pylon Expand a sustainable build?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

I don't see it [mentioned here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Category:Protoss_Build_Orders).

I think I saw some pros do it once or twice. The idea is to do pylon then immediately expand before Gateway, utilizing the Mothership Core to defend against early pressure.

If successful and you defend against early pressure, you gain a speed boost vs other openings such as Gateway expand, and spare the resources required by Forge+cannons which are mostly useless on offence.

Is it a sustainable build? What are some tips on pulling it off correctly? Vs which opponents?

Comment: the biggest risk in ladder, if your opponent cheezes you then you will lose.

Comment: It _is_ listed. Nexus first == pylon expand. Going 10 Nexus, 10 pylon would be awful economically and tech-wise.

Comment: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Nexus_First_%28vs._Terran%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is. If you scout your opponent first and see what he does.
If your opponent is Zerg and he doesn't build a pool first but a hatchery, so you can expand as well.
But make sure you place the pylon correct, I would place it at the entrance of the second base and after the second nexus you should build follow up with a forge and cannon and be ready to wall yourself in. Don't close it completely. but be ready to do so if a rush comes in. 
Get a gate and zealot or probably a sentry to be able to force field the entrance. After that you can go for your mothership core.

VS terran it's harder, since reaper can jump in. I personally don't like nexus opening vs. terran unless you scouted him and he goes for an early expansion as well.

Comment: Is this relevant only vs Terran? Why?

Comment: i mean vs terran its different. he can build reapers fast which can jump up the hills and attack from any side. so you need stalker fast. vs zerg you can only have zerglings and roaches which can't jump :)